# How can i disable "my account" and my dashboard in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, account-dashboard

How can I disable "my account" and "my dashboard" in magento?

We also don't want the link of "my account" in the top links beside log out/cart .

Answer (score 0):

T0 remove My Account link in  My account Dashboard section you need to edit below file

> app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

and add below code

```
<!-- Account link -->
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>
```

To remove My account link from top link you need to edit `default.xml` file in your theme and add below code

> app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
</referenceBlock>
```